# Can Semantic Forms / Page Forms about 200k pages?

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I am using SMW with the Semantic Forms extension on my mediawiki instance. I have defined a form that can create a page in a definied namespace.
The form by itself is working very fine. But now I have importet a big set of pages (about 170k). And suddenly the form page isn't available anymore. So if I call it, it loads for a while and then it shows an empty page (even without any mediawiki frame, completely empty).
If I import just a few hundred pages, it does still work.

Now I ask myself, is there any known bug, that Semantic Forms has a problem with big sets of pages?

Thanks, J

Comment: Do other pages fail to load? Have you run all pending jobs? i.e. set jobrunrate to 0 and set up runJobs.php as a cron job?

Comment: no, at least not any other page i've noticed.
yes, i have run all pending jobs.